# Does an APIG & Lambda API need to be wrapped in a VPC for VPN usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm still fairly new to AWS, and I'm trying to nail down architecture for trying to solve this. I'm attempting to build an API with API Gateway & Lambda, and be able to query an on-prem SQL Server DB from those Lambda functions, by using a VPG, VPN Tunnel, and Customer Gateway.

My understanding is that Lambda functions run within a VPC by default, so in order to have a data flow from my API to an on-prem server, do I need to surround that in yet another VPC, and attach my VPG directly to that?

Comment: "My understanding is that Lambda functions run within a VPC by default" does not sound correct. You have to explicitly configure the Lambda function to run within your VPC if that is what you desire.

Comment: @MarkB that came from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) — _"By default, Lambda runs your functions in a secure VPC with access to AWS services and the internet."_

Comment: Yes that's a VPC controlled by AWS that you have no visibility into. It might as well not be in a VPC at all as far as the purposes you are looking for. if you want your Lambda function to run in your VPC in order to have access to your VPG then you will have to configure it that way.

Comment: Ah, perfect! That makes much more sense. If I do deliberately run Lambda within a VPC, I should be able to attach a VPG to that then

Comment: @BenParsell worth checking aws direct connect from your VPC to your on prem datacenter or corporate network

Comment: @amittn thanks! The draw to VPN over Direct Connect is the ease of setting up compared to having to work with a local provider (i.e. ISP) to provide the connection. Maybe in the future, but we also don't really need the extra throughput.